# Use entity framework with a stored procedure to get a list that has another list in it

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a critical part of my app that is running too slow.

I have decided to move the data access for this into a stored procedure.

The results of this query is a list of orders.  That part works fine.

But each order has a list of acceptable priorities on it.  That is where I am having issues.

So I have a list in a list.  I can do two queries and try to sew the results together, but I thought I would see if Entity Framework has a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary of lists.

Since you can't actually pass your dictionary into the SQL query, you'll probably need to retrieve all the records from the DB first, then use LINQ-to-objects to perform your check, like:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new ...
var a = SomeEntity
    .ToArray()
    .Where(f => dict[f.key].Contains(f.someValue));
```

The ToArray() method pulls the entire result set into memory (there are other ways of doing it, but this is how I usually do it), and the following Where clause runs in LINQ-to-objects instead of LINQ-to-Entities, meaning your dictionary code will run fine.